# UITableViewRowAnimation is only working for the bottom cell being deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

I am having trouble getting my table view cell to show animation when being deleted. The only cell that shows any animation is the bottom cell, always the bottom no matter how big or small the table view row count is. I have a grouped table view cell if that makes any difference. I tried doing multiple things such as using the `[tableView beginUpdates` & `[tableView endUpdates` blocks as well as this code I found online:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"myAnimationId" context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:10.0]; // Set duration here

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Complete!");
}];

[myTable beginUpdates];
// my table changes
[myTable endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This is what I currently have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        NSLog(@"Recent: %@", self.recentSearchesArray[indexPath.row][0]);

        NSMutableArray *tempMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.recentSearchesArray];
        [tempMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.recentSearchesArray = tempMutableArray;
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        self.recentSearchesArray = tempMutableArray;   
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this? I appreciate any help and guidance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the last line [self.tableView reloadData]; This is forcing the whole table to be reloaded, which is probably killing your animation

Comment: @BrianShamblen: That worked but now the last cell in the row animates differently. Do you think this is an OS thing?

Comment: @BrianShamblen: After playing with this for a while. I noticed that if you don't reload the tableview the cells are off. Lets say we have this array for the cells `@[@"home", @"is", @"where", @"the", @"heart", @"is"];` if we remove (delete) we don't really "delete" it. Just the cell of that index is removed. Not the actual content and information.

Answer (score 0):

How about reloading the only cell

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

The above should work I think the problem lies in the code below

**Original Code**

```
NSMutableArray *tempMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.recentSearchesArray];
[tempMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.recentSearchesArray = tempMutableArray;
```

Where it should be just

```
[self.recentSearchesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Didn't work. Brian's answer partially worked. It isn't working for the last row, don't know if this an OS thing though.

Comment: still nothing. I got this error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete and reload the same index path (<NSIndexPath: 0xc0e2b50> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})'`